# How to merge two divs styles?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an HTML tag with a single child and each of both have their one styles.

```
<div style="font-size:12px;color:red">
   <div style="color:blue">...</div>
</div>
```

I want to merge this two tags without any changing in result. I means child styles must defeat the parent styles. In this case result must be:

```
<div style="font-size:12px;color:blue">...</div>
```

How can I do this?

**Edit:**

I have two cssText and I want to merge them in one string to put them as style attr. 
in the above example, I have 
`var st1=font-size:12px;color:red;` and `var st2=color:blue;`
and I want to merge the st1 and st2 with precedence.

Comment: [`$().css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: @Naser_Yousefi your question is a little bit unclear. HTML does this by default. An inline style already has the most precedence and something like a font-size should already be inherited from a parent. Could you provide an example perhaps of the issue that you are having so that I have a little more context?

Comment: @LucasShanley please see the edited version.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1562/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html

```
<div id=parent style="font-size:12px; color:red">
   <div id="child" style="color:blue">text</div>
</div>
```

I added IDs just to make it easy to grab those elements, there are many other ways to do it as well.

and here's the JS

```
parentClass = document.getElementById("parent").style.cssText;
childClass = document.getElementById("child").style.cssText;

document.getElementById("parent").style.cssText = parentClass+childClass;
```

Wrote the code in a very easy to understand style. Now the parent element will have both the classes of parent and child. If any of the classes repeat, then the styles of the child class will be applied, since it's written last (that's just how CSS works).

Finally, if you want, you can use removeChild() to remove the child element.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery selectors in the `mergeStyledElements` function. Set the child to primary and the parent to secondary and it will push the text from the child to the parent, remove the child, and combine the styles favoring the childs styles over the parents.

```js
var pushStyleStrings = function(str1, str2){
 let styleStr = ''; 
 function format(str){
  let rtn = {};
  str = str.replace(/\s+|\;$/g,'').split(';');
  $.each(str,function(k,v){ 
   rtn[v.split(':')[0]] = v.split(':')[1];
  });
  return rtn;
 }
 function zipObj( obj1, obj2 ){
  rtn = obj2;
  $.each(obj1,function(k,v){
   rtn[k] = v;
  });
  return rtn;
 }
 $.each(zipObj(format(str1),format(str2)),function(k,v){
  styleStr += k + ":" + v + ";";
 });
 
 return styleStr;
 
}

var mergeStyledElements = function( primary, secondary ){
  
  let $primary = $(primary),
      $secondary = $(secondary),
      $style = pushStyleStrings( $primary.attr('style'), $secondary.attr('style')),
      $text = $primary.text();

      $secondary.html($text).css($style);
}

mergeStyledElements('#primary', '#secondary');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="secondary" style="font-size:12px;color:red;">
   <div id="primary" style="color:blue;">...</div>
</div>
```